# Generalization of Wilson's theorem for prime tuples

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that Wilson's theorem states the following :

$x$ is a prime if $(\frac {\Gamma(x)+1}{x})$ is an integer .

We can extend this to Twin primes as :

$x$ and $x+2$ is prime if $(\frac {4(\Gamma(x)+1)+x}{x(x+2)})$ is an integer.

Now my question :

what is an equivalent result to the tuples of primes ?

i.e.

for given $k_0$

${\mathcal H} = (h_1, \ldots ,h_{k_0})$

and $n+ {\mathcal H } $ consists entirely of primes.

What is equivalence in terms of analog of Wilson's theorem to State the above condition ( I know it's relatively easy ) ?

(For twin primes ${\mathcal H} = (0,2)$)

Can we first prove  the infinity of primes by proving the statement  there are infinitely many integers of the form $(\frac {\Gamma(x)+1}{x})$  if x is an integer ; and then proceed in similar direction for tuples  ? -- actually this is my main question .

( Forgive my English and  type of typing I'm new here )

Comment: I think you have to pay attention to false positives such as $2=4×1/2$, so maybe the naive approach won't be enough

Comment: So maybe raising each "Wilson gamma factor" to a positive power could help rule them out.

Comment: So you can define a function $f_{m}(x)$ defined as raising the $i$-th Wilson gamma factor to the exponent of $p_{i}$ in the prime factorization of $m$. False positives will return a non integral value of $f_{m}(x)$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: You want to prove there's an infinity of twin primes, based on there being an infinity of integers of the form $(\Gamma(x)+1)/x$? Good luck!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson No ,sir that's not my main concern ( that's why I added " in some sense"  i.e. equivalent type) . I'm just curious is it possible or not with some additional Analysis ?

Comment: First off I'm trying to prove infinitude of primes using Wilson's theorem . Check this :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340329/proof-of-infinitude-of-prime-using-wilsons-theorem.                  
                                  And if I will able I'm going to proceed in same direction for tuples if possible

Comment: @Gerry Myerson you commented in support on that MSE post of mine .

Comment: Now I've edited it properly

Answer (score 4):

I assume that all $h_i$ are even.
Then $(n+h_1,n+h_2,\dots,n+h_k)$ is a prime tuple iff
$$\begin{cases}
h_1!m \equiv -1\pmod{n+h_1},\\
\dots\\
h_k!m \equiv -1\pmod{n+h_k},
\end{cases}
$$
where $m=(n-1)!$.
The system implies
$$\begin{cases}
h_k!m \equiv -\frac{h_k!}{h_1!}\pmod{n+h_1},\\
\dots\\
h_k!m \equiv -\frac{h_k!}{h_k!}\pmod{n+h_k},
\end{cases}
$$
which further combines into
$$h_k!m \equiv - \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{h_k!}{h_i!}\prod_{j=1\atop j\ne i}^k \frac{n+h_j}{h_j-h_i}\pmod{(n+h_1)\cdots (n+h_k)}.$$
That is,
$(n+h_1)\cdots (n+h_k)$ divides the numerator of $$h_k!(n-1)! + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{h_k!}{h_i!}\prod_{j=1\atop j\ne i}^k \frac{n+h_j}{h_j-h_i}.$$

**Example.** For twin primes $(n,n+2)$, we have $k=2$ with $h_1=0$ and $h_2=2$. Then the last expression becomes
$$2(n-1)!+2\frac{n+2}2 + \frac{n}{-2} = \frac{4(n-1)!+n+4}{2},$$
and thus we want $n(n+2)\mid (4(n-1)!+n+4)$.

Comment: Thank you very much , sir .

Comment: What about the main question ?

Comment: Typo is corrected. I doubt this approach can help to prove infinitude of prime twins or tuples.

Comment: @ Max Alekseyev The doubt is mutual . But I don't have very strong reason to firmly believe it .